# How to test resilience of application

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

We have a cloud application running on SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry
It makes use of other reused service e.g. audit service

to test the resilience , we need to simulate stoppage of reused service

can you please share some guidance how possibly this can be achieved?

Regards,
Apoorv

Answer (score 0):

Following the tutorial [Introduce Resilience to your Application](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-resilience.html), they add a test in their application where, in order to simulate a problem with the called service, they just point to a non-existent destination.

The test they introduce is:

```
@Test
    public void testWithFallback() {
        // Simulate a failed VDM call with non-existent destination
        DestinationAccessor.setLoader((n, o) -> Try.success(dummyDestination));

        // Assure an empty list is returned as fallback
        when()
                .get("/businesspartners")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body("", Matchers.hasSize(0));
    }
```

With the destination defined as:

```
private static final String DESTINATION_NAME = "MyErpSystem";
    private static final Destination dummyDestination = DefaultDestination.builder().property("name", DESTINATION_NAME).property("URL", "foo").build();
```

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Kr,
kepair